# how to re-train Saved linear regression ML model in pyspark when new data is coming

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark

I trained a **linear regression** model using **pyspark ml** and save it.now i want to **re-train** it on the bases of new data batch.. is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you use pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression to train, and then you get a pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegressionModel, that is what you have saved.
AFIK, the model can't be refitted, you have to use the regression fit again to get a new model.